# Are WordPress questions on-topic for SO or not?

Tags: discussion, scope

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress/info) says that only questions about writing extensions for WordPress are on-topic for SO, and all other questions should be asked on the [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) SE site.

That doesn't seem to be the community consensus; see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334606/wordpress-3-8-1-adding-parenthesis-after-youtube-video) which has been up-voted and even protected.  (The review system just dinged me for voting against re-opening that question.)

So either the tag wiki needs editing, or a whole bunch of questions need closing.  Which?

Comment: What? Vote to close. With prejudice. I'll flag it for kod attention asking for migration. (The protection is in place because of several "me too" answers; it's not implying that the question is worth having around.)

Comment: @Pëkka, the selected answer was *`the problem is from youtube embed code not WordPress`*. The current close vote is incorrect.

Comment: @brasofilo I don't follow. It's a question about using Wordpress, no? That the answer happens to be YouTube related doesn't really change that. It's most definitely off topic on SO from where I'm standing. It might work on WP.SE.

Comment: @Pëkka, my understanding is that is off-topic because it is about YouTube... But I shouldn't have used *"is incorrect"* in my last comment...

Comment: @brasofilo the question is arguably one that is likely to come up again in a WP context as long as the bug isn't fixed, though. (In fact, there are two deleted "I have this problem too" answers in that very question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3897619/revisions) to make the difference a bit clearer on the tag wiki (emphasis on my edit):

> This tag is for programming-specific questions related to WordPress, *especially those that involve a mix of languages and technologies (PHP, MySQL, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery and others). Questions about plugin and theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices and server configuration* are best asked on Stack Exchange [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Mostly, what's off-topic at WordPress Development are questions that are pure or mainly CSS, JS/jQuery, MySQL related.

What I've seen on Stack Overflow and read here on Meta Stack Overflow is that any kind of WordPress programming related questions are on-topic on SO, even though there's a dedicated site for it.